# Show that subspace contains unique element with minimal $L^2$-norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S = \{x \in L^2(0,1) : \int_0^1 x(t) dt = 1\}$. I want to show that $S$ containts a unique element with minimal $L^2$-norm and I want to find this element.

I start of by finding a minimal element $x \in S$:

$$ 1 = \int_0^1 x(t) dt = \int_0^1 x(t)\cdot1\ dt= \langle\,x,1\rangle = |\langle\,x,1\rangle| \leq ||x||\cdot||1|| = ||x||$$

Solving the inequality above with equality gives us that a minimal element is given by $x = 1$.

How can I show that this $x$ is the *unique* minimal solution in $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition for equality in C-S inequality : $ \langle f, g \rangle=\|f\| \|g||$ ($f,g \neq 0$) if and only if $f=cg$ for some positive number $c$. So if $x$ is any element of norm $1$ in your set the $x$must be a constant function and since its integral is $1$ the constant has to be $1$.